# How to set name attribute in React Quill?

Tags: reactjs

I want to set a name attribute in React Quill, but there are something wrong for this operate.

I set a name attribute in `<ReactQuill >`, but when I check element in google, I can not find name attribute.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactQuill from 'quill'

class Editor extends React.Component {
    ...
    some code
    ...

    render(){
       return(
          <ReactQuill
             name='abc'
          >
       )
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using this - https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill

Comment: I don't find any package with name `quill` as you imported.

Comment: Put your whole code in Codesanbox or alike will be better for other to debug